# Google Maps API printing - tiles partially missing

Tags: google-maps-api, printing

I am working on a single page application using the Google Maps API that features a print option (among other things). I am currently using a slightly adapted version of the printAnyMaps function found in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/glenn/6mx21ted/) to print the map. My problem: Sometimes a row of tiles is partially missing (see screenshot below).
[image: Screenshot]

I applied some border styling for easier debugging:

```
 #main-map { border: 1px solid blue; }
 #main-map div { border: 1px solid red; }
```

What could possibly cause this shift? Is there a promise I should be waiting on before calling `window.print()`?

The blue border styling actually shows that the map container covers the intended area, so it is indeed a tile/map content error I think.

Comment: Looks like the retrieving of files (image tiles) is getting interrupted with another request. fiddler2/firebug might be able to show you the requests and the responses from the google servers. Though if you show all your code might spot other anomalies.

Comment: I tried and it is working fine.

Comment: Seems to be [related to this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426294)